# Java - Obtain text within script tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am using the Jsoup library to read a URL. This url has text within a few `<script>` tags. Is it possible for me to obtain the text within each `<script>` tag? Please note that I am not asking to parse a Javascript file as I am already aware JSoup does not allow that. The actual source code of the URL has text within a script tag, I need that.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").timeout(10000).get();

Element div = doc.select("script").first();
for (Element element : div.children()) {
System.out.println(element.toString());
}
```

This is what one of the script tags look like from the source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
...
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes. You can use [Element#getElementsByTag()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByTag%28java.lang.String%29) to get all the `script` tag . Each script tags will be represented by the [DataNode](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/DataNode.html).

```
 Document doc =Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780517/java-obtain-text-within-script-tag-using-jsoup").timeout(10000).get();
 Elements scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("script");

 for (Element element :scriptElements ){                
        for (DataNode node : element.dataNodes()) {
            System.out.println(node.getWholeData());
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------");            
  }
```

Comment: thank you @KenChan, It worked perfectly, i'm using `String scriptdata = node.getWholeData();` **But as only get the second script on the page?**

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, you could use the [`Element#html()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html%28%29) method that returns the inner html of an element.

**Since 1.11.1**: *Use efficient [`Element#selectFirst()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#selectFirst-java.lang.String-) method to find the script element.*

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").timeout(10000).get();
Element scriptElement = doc.selectFirst("script");

// Don't forget to check scriptElement is not null...

String jsCode = scriptElement.html();
```

**Up to Jsoup 1.10.3**: *Combine [`Element#select()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-) and [`Elements#first()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first--) calls to find the script element.*

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").timeout(10000).get();
Element scriptElement = doc.select("script").first();

// Don't forget to check scriptElement is not null...

String jsCode = scriptElement.html();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements scripts = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
for (Element script : scripts) {
    System.out.println(script.data());
}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

According to your case the solution will be as below.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").timeout(10000).get();
Elements scripts = doc.select("script");

for (Element script : scripts) {
    String type = script.attr("type");
    if (type.contentEquals("text/javascript")) {
        String scriptData = script.data(); // your text from the script
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify the code with "cssQuery" syntax as Elements scripts = doc.select("script[type=text/javascript]");